# react-stormpath routing issue

Tags: reactjs, router

I am using react-stormpath with react. Whenver I am using strormapath router in place of react router, it's giving me an error.

stormpath router i am importing like this:-

`import ReactStormpath, {Router,HomeRoute, LoginRoute, AuthenticatedRoute } from 'react-stormpath';`

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {path, component, getChildRoutes, indexRoute}). If you meant to render
>   a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object
>   using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render
>   method of `Router`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of react-stormpath are you using?

Comment: The app.js code from the sample project (https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express-react-example) looks like this: http://pastie.org/10935200

Comment: As shown, you'll need to first import Route from 'react-router'

Comment: Your pastie is offline. Could you include a webpackbin or add your code example to the question so we can make better suggestion on how to solve your problem.